# ngbtypeahead angular 4 returns Property 'length' does not exist on type '{}' error

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I want to implement autocomplete in one of the text fields. I am trying to use bootstrap typeahead by following this simple example.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#basic

However I get the following error on compilation.

```
ERROR in C:/Users/eclipse-workspace/c-UI/src/app/send-email/send-email.component.ts (33,24): Property 'length' does not exist on type '{}'.
ERROR in C:/Users/eclipse-workspace/c-UI/src/app/send-email/send-email.component.ts (34,59): Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

## html

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  [ngbTypeahead]="states">
```

## component.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

const states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa'];

export class SendEmailComponent {

  public model: any;

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  text$.pipe(
  debounceTime(200),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
    : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
)
  }
```

Please help.

Comment: I tried the above code. I did not encounter any errors?

Comment: @wentjun may i know your angular version?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into one of the stackblitz links over here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#basic

Comment: The above link uses Angular 7 and I use 4 . Wanted to know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hmm... It might! Especially the RxJS operators. I think there might be some differences in terms of syntax.

Answer (score 0):

since term is not a string you can define it in the beginning of your arrow function like this :

```
  map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
    : states.filter((v:string) => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
)
```